# iOS Xcode 10: Private framework with pods dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm not able to archive a framework with Cocoapods dependencies.

I would like to archive it and than use vendored-framework Cocoapods setting to share it.

Any tips?

Comment: What have you tried and what errors did get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging and a lot of work I finally completed my mkission to build an Umbrella Framewrok as a Private Vendored CocoaPods.

[Here is the full guide step by step!](https://medium.com/@andreamiotz/ios-umbrella-framework-with-cocoapods-57d2d3c2daa9?source=friends_link&sk=af4816d039f901021291474ff8b45e16)